# How do I automate testing installing an iPhone app?

Tags: automated-testing, mobile, mobile-automation, iphone

I am familiar with writing automation for testing web pages in a browser using selenium, rspec, jasmine and similar tools.

Now I want to test a new iPhone application that we have developed.

The main thing I want to automate right now is the sign-up processes.

These include steps such as:

1. User installs application on their iPhone
2. User bring up application on their iPhone
3. User logs in with known email address to existing account
4. User is taken to home page and see account details

**What tools can I use to automate this and be part of our build?**

I want automation that can fit in with our current (rspec based) test suite and be part of our CircleCI integrated build.  This question is similar to [Tools for testing iPhone apps](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/1161/8992) but different enough in the details for me to post this.  I favor Ruby for language (hence rspec) but not sure if that would be part of any solutions.